# Actionscript 3 - how do I stop/pause a function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, onclick

I have a main menu page with a start button, then on the slideshow I have a restart button which goes to the main menu. How do I stop the slideshow when I go back to main menu? Right now I go back to main menu by hiding the slideshow components and showing the main page components, but I'm unable to stop the slideshow:

```
startButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStartClick);
restartButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onRestartClick);

function onStartClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    populateArray();
    TweenLite.to(titleScreen, 1, {alpha:0});
    TweenLite.to(startButton, 1, {alpha:0});
    TweenLite.to(theImage, 1, {alpha:1, delay:1});
    TweenLite.to(infoBox, 1, {alpha:1, delay:1});
    TweenLite.to(restartButton, 1, {alpha:1, delay:1});
    beginImage();
}

//Go back to main menu
function onRestartClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    TweenLite.to(theImage, 1, {alpha:0});
    TweenLite.to(infoBox, 1, {alpha:0});
    TweenLite.to(restartButton, 1, {alpha:0});
    TweenLite.to(titleScreen, 1, {alpha:1, delay:1});
    TweenLite.to(startButton, 1, {alpha:1, delay:1});
}


function populateArray():void {
    //takes the properties defined in the XML and stores them into arrays
    var i:Number;
    for (i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
        imageArray[i]=xml.images[i].pic;
        titleArray[i]=xml.images[i].cn;
        painterArray[i]=xml.images[i].en;
        dateArray[i]=xml.images[i].misc;
    }
}

function beginImage():void {

    //load description
    infoBox.theArtist.text=painterArray[currPainting];
    infoBox.theTitle.text=titleArray[currPainting];
    infoBox.theDate.text=dateArray[currPainting];

    theImage.scaleX=1;
    theImage.scaleY=1;

    var imageLoader = new Loader();

    //actually loads the URL defined in the image array
    imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(imageArray[currPainting]));
    //adds a listener for what to do when the image is done loading
    imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imgLoaded);

    function imgLoaded(event:Event):void {

        //add the image and get the dimensions to center the image
        theImage.addChild(imageLoader);

        theImage.x = (stage.stageWidth/2) - (imageLoader.content.width / 2);
        theImage.y = (stage.stageHeight/2) - (imageLoader.content.height / 2);

        finalX = (stage.stageWidth/2) - (imageLoader.content.width * .8 / 2);
        finalY = (stage.stageHeight/2) - (imageLoader.content.height * .8 / 2);

        //start tween function
        easeIn();

    }
}

function easeIn():void {
    TweenLite.to(theImage, 11.6, {scaleX:.8, scaleY:.8, x:finalX, y:finalY, onComplete:hideStuff});
    TweenLite.to(theImage, 1, {alpha:1, overwrite:0});
    TweenLite.to(infoBox, 1, {alpha:1});
}

function hideStuff():void {
    TweenLite.to(theImage, 1, {alpha:0, onComplete:nextImage});
    TweenLite.to(infoBox, 1, {alpha:0});
}

function nextImage():void {
    //take out the image that was just displayed
    imageArray.splice(currPainting,1);
    titleArray.splice(currPainting,1);
    painterArray.splice(currPainting,1);
    dateArray.splice(currPainting,1);

    //remove the picture
    theImage.removeChildAt(0);

    //start over
    if (imageArray.length==0) {
        TweenLite.to(theImage, 1, {alpha:0});
        TweenLite.to(infoBox, 1, {alpha:0});
        TweenLite.to(restartButton, 1, {alpha:0});
        TweenLite.to(titleScreen, 1, {alpha:1, delay:1});
        TweenLite.to(startButton, 1, {alpha:1, delay:1});
    } else {
        beginImage();
    }
}
```

How do I stop beginImage() (which fires populateArray, easeIn, hideStuff and nextImage) after I go back to main menu?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you ever drop a loaded image off all the arrays? Do you then need to reload it from the Internet? If yes, you shuold rework most of your logic to accomplish this.

Comment: You cannot stop TweenLite.to becouse it doesnt have a reference. Try using tweenArray and add tweens to it, then you can check if there is any tween and if it is running stop it. To stop loading - you can't! Once initiated it loads! Although you can remove event listener from loader. Later you can also try imageLoader = null.